# Physical meaning of adding two spin operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, observables

When we add who spin operators, one in $x$ and the other in $z$ direction, dose it make any physical sense? Do the eigenvalues of this sum is also equal to a sum of their eigenvalues?

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/498675/).

Comment: Interesting question. Consider that if you consider the base $|m\rangle$ of $\hat{L}_z$ eigenstates, then $\hat{L}_x=\hat{L}_++\hat{L}_-$. So you have now $\hat{L}_z+(\hat{L}_++\hat{L}_-)/2$ where $\hat{L}_z$ has $|m\rangle$ eigenstates, $\hat{L}_-$ has coherent states as eigenstates and $\hat{L}_+$ has no eigenstates. I don't know so if there is an eigenstate of the sum of this operators, but it's interesting: good luck finding it!

Comment: You already give a calculable example in your question. $\sigma_x+\sigma_z$ has eigenvalues $\sqrt 2 and -\sqrt 2$ which is not $1+1=2$ or $-1-1=-2$. Another information: density matrix, e.g. qubit case, can be written into form of $\frac{I+\vec{r}\cdot \vec{\sigma}}{2}$.

Comment: @RobTan (angular momentum) coherent states are not eigenstates of $\hat L_-$.  The lowering operators do not have eigenstates in a finite dimensional space except for the null vector.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero finite dimensional because $-j<m<j$? Ok, I didn't know that

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways of understanding the question.

Given the unit vector $\hat n=(\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta)$, the general linear combination $\hat S_{\hat n}=\hat n\cdot \vec S= n_xS_x+n_yS_y+n_zS_z$ is a legitimate spin operator.

The eigenstates of $\hat S_{\hat n}$ are spin-states in the direction of $\hat  n$.  The eigenvalues of $\hat S_{\hat n}$ are... $\pm\hbar/2$.  Mathematically, the operators $\hat S_i$ do not commute, so you cannot simply add the eigenvalues of each operator.

Physically, the direction of the quantization axis is arbitrary, so choosing to quantize along $\hat n$ will result in the same possible outcomes as quantizing along $\hat z$, *i.e.* $\pm \hbar/2$. (Remember that these possible outcomes are the eigenvalues.) By the same logic one concludes correctly that the eigenvalues of $\hat S_i$ are all the same, and in fact, in a $(2j+1)\times(2j+1)$ dimensional space of a particle with total angular momentum $j$, the eigenvalues of $J_i$ are all the same.

Note that specific combinations of the type above are extremely useful in quantum cryptography and at the core of the famous [BB84 quantum crypto protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BB84).

The second way to understand your question is adding spin operators operating on different systems, *i.e.* $\hat S_i=\hat S^{(1)}_i+\hat S^{(2)}_i$ with $\hat S_i$ the total spin of the system along axis $i$.  Since all operators acting in space 1 commute with all operators acting in space 2, the eigenvalues are then additive, in the same way that the total energy of a system with Hamiltonian $\hat H_1+\hat H_2$ is $E^{(1)}_{n_1}+E^{(2)}_{n_2}$.  In your specific case, the eigenvalues of your total spin operators would be the $1,0,0,-1$.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the base $|j,m\rangle$ with $\hat{L}_z|j,m\rangle=\hbar m|j,m\rangle$ then you can consider a generic state as a combination of elements of this base, and impose it is an eigenstate of $\hat{L}_z+(\hat{L}_++\hat{L}_-)/2$
$$
\left(
\hat{L}_z+\frac{\hat{L}_++\hat{L}_-}{2}
\right)
\sum\limits_{j,m}
c_{jm}|j,m\rangle
=
\hbar
\alpha
\sum\limits_{j,m}
c_{jm}|j,m\rangle
$$
and this way you'll obtain the equation
$$
\sum\limits_{j,m}
c_{jm} \hbar m|j,m\rangle
+
\frac{1}{2}
\sum\limits_{j,m}
c_{jm}
\hbar
\sqrt{
(j-m)(j+m+1)
}
|j,m+1\rangle
+
\frac{1}{2}
\sum\limits_{j,m}
c_{jm}
\hbar
\sqrt{
(j+m)(j-m+1)
}
|j,m-1\rangle
=
\hbar
\alpha
\sum\limits_{j,m}
c_{jm}|j,m\rangle
$$
that you can rearrange as
$$
\sum\limits_{j,m}
\left(
m c_{jm}
+
\frac{1}{2}
\sqrt{(j-m+1)(j+m)}
c_{j(m-1)}
+
\frac{1}{2}
\sqrt{(j+m+1)(j-m)}
c_{j(m+1)}
-
\alpha c_{jm}
\right)
|j,m\rangle
=
0
$$
Since $|j,m\rangle$ are orthonormal you'll find
$$
m c_{jm}
+
\frac{1}{2}
\sqrt{(j-m+1)(j+m)}
c_{j(m-1)}
+
\frac{1}{2}
\sqrt{(j+m+1)(j-m)}
c_{j(m+1)}
-
\alpha c_{jm}
=
0
$$
that you can ideally solve as a recurrence relation. I stop here since I don't know if a solution exists and what is its form, but that's what I would do in absence of other ideas.

Comment: Note that if this equation implies $c_{jm}=0\,\forall\,j,m$ and forall $\alpha\in\text{R}$ there are not eigenstates and so no eigenvalues: in fact what I'm asking here is if eigenstates exist. Once responded, if someone is able to, we could determine eigenvalues and respond to your question.