# Operator Systems vs Operator Algebras

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, mathematical-physics

I am someone who works in mathematics, works with operators, and tries to interpret things in terms of a "toy" QM that doesn't necessarily have anything to do with actual QM. Two things in the below, which outlines the "toy" QM that I employ, that might not happen in any real QM theory is that A) I have a system with trivial dynamics and B) this means I can talk about sequential measurement.

This might be a maths question rather than a physics question (but if it it a maths question rather than a physics question, then it needs to be asked in a different way somewhere else).

---

Suppose a QM system given by Hilbert space $\mathsf{H}$, and suppose the system state is given by a state $\varphi:B(\mathsf{H})\to \mathbb{C}$. Consider a finite spectrum observable with eigendecomposition $$f=\sum_{\lambda\in \sigma(f)}\lambda \,p_\lambda,$$ a self-adjoint element of $B(\mathsf{H})$. Given the state $\varphi$, we say that the expectation of $f$ is:
$$\mathbb{E}_\varphi(f)=\varphi(f),$$
and the probability that we measure $\varphi$ with $f$ and get $f=\lambda$ is
$$\mathbb{P}_\varphi[f=\lambda]=\varphi(p_\lambda),$$
and the state collapses to:
$$\widetilde{p_\lambda}\varphi= \frac{\varphi(p_\lambda \cdot p_\lambda)}{\varphi(p_\lambda)}.$$
If we represent $\varphi$ as a vector state $\xi_\varphi$, the wave function collapse is $\xi_\varphi\mapsto p_\lambda \xi_\varphi$ in projective Hilbert space.

If we assume trivial dynamics (the unitary operator is the identity), then we can, after measuring $\varphi$ with $f$, getting $f=\lambda$, and finding the system state is $\widetilde{p_{\lambda}}\varphi$, take another finite spectrum observable
$$g=\sum_{\mu \in\sigma(g)}\mu\,q_\mu,$$
and measure the state $\widetilde{p_{\lambda}}\varphi$ with it. We might write that:
$$\mathbb{P}_{\widetilde{p_{\lambda}}\varphi}[g=\mu]=\frac{\varphi(p_\lambda q_\mu p_\lambda)}{\varphi(p_\lambda)}.$$

Now we know that in general $gf$ is not an observable but I consider this sequential measurement "$f$ then $g$" (I have used $g\succ f$) an object with values in $\sigma(f)\times \sigma(g)\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, and crucially it gives meaning to quantities like $q_\mu p_\lambda$ via:
$$\mathbb{P}_{\varphi}[(g\succ f)=(\mu,\lambda)]=\varphi(|q_\mu p_\lambda|^2),$$

where of course $|q_\mu p_\lambda|^2=p_\lambda q_\mu p_{\lambda}$.

---

This to me gives an intuitive algebra (product/multiplication) structure on observables: that if $f,g\in B(\mathsf{H})$ are observables, the quantity $gf\in B(\mathsf{H})$, not an observable, is related to an $\mathbb{R}^2$-valued object $g\succ f$. So when I look at the place $\mathcal{A}\subset B(\mathsf{H})$ where observables live, I want it to have an algebra structure, $f,g\in \mathcal{A}\implies gf\in\mathcal{A}$.

What I still don't understand, and I understand it is still an issue with mainstream QM, is that $g+f$ is an observable whenever $f$ and $g$ are. So in addition to the multiplication I have $f,g\in \mathcal{A}\implies f+g\in \mathcal{A}$. I don't expect today for someone to help interpret this (beyond perhaps using some observable-state duality).

Let us summarise right here (glossing over a desire that $\mathcal{A}$ be complete) that we want $\mathcal{A}$ to be a $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra. It allows us to make sense of $gf$ and we just kind of put up with $g+f$.

---

Recently however I have seen people in the area of maths I work in use [Operator Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_system). These are closed, self-adjoint unital subspaces of $\mathcal{O}\subset B(\mathsf{H})$ (or $\mathcal{O}\subset \mathcal{A}$), where we don't require the algebra structure $f,g\in\mathcal{O}\implies gf\in \mathcal{O}$ but we *do* require the vector structure:
$$f,g\in\mathcal{O}\implies g+f\in\mathcal{O}.$$

Finally, hopefully a focused question:

> Why would a QM theory work with operator systems rather than operator algebras?

Comment: Why is $f,g\in \mathcal{A}\rightarrow f+g\in \mathcal{A}$ an issue? Observables include all bounded self-adjoint linear operators, so if $f,g$ are observables, so should be $f+g$.

Comment: @MengCheng note we need not include ALL bounded self-adjoint linear operators here... but both operator spaces and systems are closed under this addition. Why is this an issue? See here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/498675/

Comment: Your issue is more about actually designing a measurement for $f+g$, but as a matter of principle, there should be a way to measure $f+g$ (maybe the measurement will be completely different from either of $f$ or $g$, maybe it is very complicated, but always possible), and this is a basic axiom of the mathematical foundation of QM.  Here is a simple example: take a spin-1/2, $A=\sigma^x$ and $B=\sigma^z$.  Then $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\sigma^x + \sigma^z)$ is measuring spin along $\pi/4$ direction in the x-z plane. It is a perfectly fine observable and in this case we know how to measure it.

Comment: @MengCheng Have we any hope of interpreting the sum of a position and momentum observable? I note the question is closer to asking why should observables live in a space with a product. The vector structure present in both the algebra and system.

Comment: well it depends on what you mean by "interpreting". It almost seems like you would like to have a concrete protocol for a physical experiment to accept something as "observable". But that is not necessary. Observables are things that can *in principle* be measured, but don't have to be things that you can immediately construct a measurement protocol in terms of experimental techniques you already know.

Comment: @MengCheng thank you for your engagement but these matters are an aside to my actual question.

Comment: I do think these matters are at the heart of your question. But anyway, that's just my point of view.